# Behavior of SDL_AddEventWatch in SDL

Tags: c, sdl

I'm currently trying to learn SDL, so there's probably something obvious I need to do.

There is a function called `SDL_AddEventWatch`, which both the header file and the wiki describe as:

> Add a function which is called when an event is added to the queue.

However, this appears to only work when initializing the window and when using `SDL_PollEvent`.

I init SDL, add my watcher, and when I init the window. The watcher gets called, but after that, it does not get called until I poll it, when it is called repeatedly until the queue is empty.

my full code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include <linux/types.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_video.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_events.h>

volatile char flag = 0;

int watcher(void *userdata, SDL_Event* event){
    if(event->type != SDL_WINDOWEVENT){
        return 0;
    }
    printf("vent");
    printf(".win");
    printf(".%d",event->window.event);
    switch(event->window.event){
        case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE: {
            printf("quit");
            SDL_Quit();
            exit(0);
            break;
        }
        case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SHOWN: {
            printf("shown");
            break;
        }
        case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_HIDDEN: {
            printf("hid");
            break;
        }
        
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(){

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    
    SDL_AddEventWatch(watcher,NULL);
    
    printf("make  window");
    getchar(); 
    
    
    #define width 1000
    #define height 600
    SDL_Window*     window = SDL_CreateWindow("test",0,0,width,height,0);
    SDL_Surface*    surfinUSA = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    
    printf("draw");
    getchar(); 
    
////draw
    Uint32* pixelRay = (Uint32*)(surfinUSA->pixels);
    
    Uint32 maped = SDL_MapRGB(surfinUSA->format,255,255,255);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < surfinUSA->w; i++){
        
        double xMath = ((double)i) / 10;
        
        int y = (height/2)+(100.0*sin(xMath))+(100.0*sin(xMath/1.2));
        
        pixelRay[i+(width*y)] = maped;
        
        //waits for next frame, aparently
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
    }   
    
////poke
    printf("poll");
    getchar(); 
    //single poll, multipule calls?
    SDL_PollEvent(NULL);
    
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

Comment: You _need_ to call `SDL_PollEvent` in a loop. Callbacks are _synchronous_. They do _not_ "interrupt" your program like signal handlers do.

Comment: Is there not a way to get a signal like behavior out of SDL? :(